# Показать скрытую форму через открытую

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте! На главном окне у меня присутствует авторизация, при успешном её прохождении появляется новое окно, а главное скрывается:

```
mainForm mainForm = new mainForm();
mainForm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Как можно при закрытии появившегося окна вновь показать главную форму, которая скрыта?

Comment: Чтобы открылось старое окно, надо создать событие в коде старого окна(mainForm.Closed).

Answer (score 1):

```
mainForm.FormClosed += (object s, FormClosedEventArgs ev) => { this.Show(); };
```

Решение моей проблемы, прописываемое прямо в код после создания mainForm.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте событие закрытия окна(Form.Closed или Form.Closing) и просто таким же образом покажите старую форму.

Comment: Так уже делал, но по сути таким способом я создаю лишь копию главного окна, а само главное окно по-прежнему существует, только скрыто.

Comment: Прямо в коде, где открыли новое окно надо создать событие...

Comment: А не могли бы вы подсказать, как это реализовать? А то в С# совсем новичок.

Answer (score 0):

Вы шутите ?

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form frm = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                this.Show();
        }
    }
```

```csharp
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

    }
```